# Grep with multiple conditions and num lines trailing

Tags: linux, grep, command, arguments

I have a basic log file that I'm trying to parse using grep.

My command is as follows:

```
grep 'Rate for the playback =\|Dumping\|ERROR\|*** Starting' ENCL_overnight_loop20160118_173202.log | egrep -v -A40 'DumpDataComp'
```

I've also tried

```
grep -e 'Rate for the playback =\|Dumping\|ERROR\|*** Starting' -e -A40 'DumpDataComp' ENCL_overnight_loop20160118_173202.log
```

Neither of these commands seem to account for the -A40 argument. The grep works in finding the condition, but the 40 lines that trail do not print.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want to see `DumpDataComp` or exclude it? Your two tries don't seem to try to do the same.

Comment: I've included the 'DumpDataComp' in both examples. It should be included with the -A40 parameter applied to just that condition

Comment: Can you add an excerpt of the log file? Is `Rate for the playback` on the same line as `DumpDataComp`?